# Font awesome not working in Mozilla

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, firefox, font-awesome

I am using Font-awesome for a webpage, and it works fine in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. Instead of `class="fa-star"`, I get little rectangles.

I did a research and found that I have to put

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

at the top of .htaccess file. It still doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi, you use fontawesome via CDN or you downloaded the CSS file?

Comment: I use external link:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header that would need to be set on the external site (which it already is), not your site. If this wasn't set then Chrome and Safari would not work either. Using the Dev Tools in Mozilla, are you able to determine what font/CSS is being used?